# Inflating AppBarLayout with Toolbar + TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-tablayout

I currently have a DrawerLayout in my main.xml. There's a Toolbar wrapped in an AppBarLayout, and then a simple LinearLayout to swap out fragments.

One of the fragments I navigate to, I want it to contain a TabLayout for a ViewPager of fragments. Currently, I have both of these in the fragment's layout file, but this causes a drop shadow to appear between the Toolbar and the TabLayout, which is something I don't want. I also don't want to use setElevation() because it won't work for pre-Lollipop devices.

A possible solution would be to inflate the AppBarLayout from my fragment, so that it holds both the Toolbar+Tabs. However, I'm not really sure how to do this, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is my main.xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.lumivote.lumivote.ui.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="#333"
        app:itemTextColor="#333"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here is my fragment's xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.alexdao.democracy.ui.candidate_tab.CandidateListFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/myPrimaryColor"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix my problem I ended up putting the Toolbar, TabLayout, and ViewPager all in my MainActivity.

main_activity.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="#333"
        app:itemTextColor="#333"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then, in all of my fragments, I set the visibility for the TabLayout and the ViewPager programmatically in onCreateView:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
}
```

Of course, in the fragment with tabs, you would want to set the visibility to `View.VISIBLE` instead of `View.GONE`.

Comment: This is an interesting approach

Answer (score 12):

You are able to have separate toolbar for each fragment. Its possible to set fragments toolbar as activity actionbar. Example code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

It should be possible to have titles, icons and other stuff as well.
With it you can mimic shadow on pre lollipop devices, no matter what you have on them.

Comment: I checked performance on my lollipop device and old htc desire x with api 16. Fragment transition with own toolbars were really smooth and cpu usage never reached 25% (I was tapping replace button few times per second)

Comment: This is a great solution, but What if I use Activity with Navigation drawer, and want that Hamburger(animating) icon also on (my fragment's) Toolbar?

Answer (score 5):

I modified the solution given by [bleeding182](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1837367/bleeding182) and got it to work for AppBarLayout as well (to resolve the problem pointed out by [bopa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/286172/bopa)).

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.appbar).setElevation(0);
    }
    super.onAttach(context);

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.appbar).setElevation(R.dimen.toolbar_elevation);
    }
}
```

What I did was replace the call to getSupportActionBar() by giving an ID to my AppBarLayout and then calling findViewById() on it and then calling setElevation on its result. Tested on API 23.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue where I wanted a `TabLayout` just inside of one fragment.

Without changing any other code you can solve this by using `onAttach` and `onDetach` inside your fragment with the TabLayout.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // todo add some further checks, e.g. instanceof, actionbar != null

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        ((AppCompatActivity) activity).getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()
                .setElevation(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_elevation));
    }
}
```

Be sure to set the same elevation on your TabLayout and everything works fine! ;D

Comment: won't work in his case because the AppBarLayout drops the shadow

Comment: You could better use `onStart` and `onStop`, this because when a fragment is replaced and added to the backstack, it isn't detached and `onDetach` isn't called, so the shadow remains `0dp`. But this fixed my issue, thanks David!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add TabLayout programmatically from Fragment in wich you need TabLayout

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablay, null);
appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.appbar);
appBarLayout.addView(tabLayout, new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

and remove TabLayout from AppBar in onDetach()

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    appBarLayout.removeView(tabLayout);
    super.onDetach();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Artem_lens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3165400/artem-iens) approach worked for me with some modifications.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.partial_tab_layout,
            container,
            false);
    mAppBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    mAppBarLayout.addView(mTabLayout,
            new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    ...
}
```

And removing the view at `onDestroyView()`

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    mAppBarLayout.removeView(mTabLayout);
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple in the XML. Just add the following code to your AppBarLayout: `app:elevation="0dp"`. So the AppBarLayout should look like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```